# Extract tables from view using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a view which consist of two tables.

**Example**:

Table1:

```
 create table t1
 (
    a  varchar(10),
    b  varchar(10)
 )
```

Table2:

```
 create table t2
 (
    a  varchar(10),
    b  varchar(10)
 )
```

With some data:

Table1:

```
 insert into t1 values('xyz','abc')
 insert into t1 values('ttt','aaa')
```

Table2:

```
 insert into t2 values('stu','def')
 insert into t2 values('sss','bbb')
```

Creating view:

```
 create view view1 as select * from t1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM t2;
```

Now `view1` look like this:

```
  a      b
 ----------
 xyz    abc
 ttt    aaa
 stu    def
 sss    bbb
```

**Note:** Now question comes here is that "How can I extract view in my Stored Procedure?" I want to modify some `tables` which are presents in the `view` but I can't modify `view`(because it may contains number of tables), So I need to extract it and modify each `table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific function for extracting the underlying Tables from a View. You would need to have the view include the Primary Key for each Table. Then update each Table in a separate query from the correct Key in the View.

Table1:

```
 create table t1
 (
    [ID] [Int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [a]  varchar(10),
    [b]  varchar(10)
  CONSTRAINT [PK_t1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
    [ID] ASC
  )
 )
```

Table2:

```
 create table t2
 (
    [ID] [Int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    [a]  varchar(10),
    [b]  varchar(10)
  CONSTRAINT [PK_t2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
  (
    [ID] ASC
  )
 )
```

Your View

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS 
SELECT t1.ID AS t1ID, null AS t2ID, * FROM t1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT null AS t1ID, t2.ID AS t2ID, * FROM t2;
```

Now you can always get the t1ID and t2ID out of the View, and use that for updates on the base tables.

Updates could be made like this...

```
UPDATE t1 SET b = 'value'
FROM view1
WHERE t1.ID = view1.t1ID
--Add other criteria here
```

Comment: I am getting both tables ID's in single column that is t1.ID  as per your query tested. So updation will not allowed for values which have repeated.

Comment: For update --> `UPDATE view1
SET b = 'bala'
WHERE t1ID = '1'`

Comment: A VIEW cannot be updated, you must update the TABLE. Also t1ID is an INTEGER type, so you don't put it in quotes.

UPDATE t1 SET b = 'bala'
FROM view1
WHERE t1.ID = view1.tiID

Comment: Thank you so much. Well! Can I get `table names` separately from `view`? If `view` contains 50 `tables` how can I get those `table names` and update that? Thanks

Comment: Andriy, you are right... I wrote the View without testing it. I have updated the answer to be correct. Meem, I should point out that I think there is a better solution to your data need here... it might involve rethinking the structure of the data. However assuming there was no other option... the example above will work. It's just very messy, aggregating a bunch of tables into a view... then using the view to update them.

Comment: I can't understand why I would want to use `UPDATE t1 SET b = 'value' FROM view1 WHERE t1.ID = view1.t1ID` and not the simple `UPDATE t1 SET b = 'value';` What do I gain?

Comment: If by "a bunch" of tables you mean more than two, then it might be better to use a different method of combining them under a single view, e.g. `SELECT 't1' AS tablename, * FROM t1 UNION ALL SELECT 't2' AS tablename, * FROM t2 UNION ALL ...`. That way you introduce only one additional column and will be able to re-use an existing one, `ID`, in your queries.

Comment: I am assuming the OP has some kind of business logic embedded in the VIEW, making it an easy way to see what rows need an update. You could also want to do something like this...

UPDATE t1 SET b = t2.a + t1.a FROM view1 WHERE t1.ID = view1.t1ID